# ffplay video playing with slider where i can slider to any position of the video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

is it possible to slide to a specific location of video in FFplay?

Like how we do in VLC when we open a video a slider will be a bottom using which we can move to any part of the video is it possible in ffplay?
using either commands or any GUI

Answer (score 8):

### There is no slider / progression bar / seek bar

ffplay has no on-screen-display (OSD) bar for seeking.

### Use [mpv](https://mpv.io/) intead

[mpv](https://mpv.io/)  is like a "super" ffplay, has an OSD bar, and can use the same filters as ffplay. mpv is a real player. ffplay is more of an  example or a proof-of-concept.

### Available controls for ffplay

From the [`ffplay` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html#While-playing):

- <kbd>s</kbd> - Step to the next frame.  Pause if the stream is not already paused, step to the next video frame, and pause.
- <kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd> - Seek backward/forward 10 seconds.
- <kbd>down</kbd>/<kbd>up</kbd> - Seek backward/forward 1 minute.
- <kbd>Page Down</kbd>/<kbd>Page Up</kbd> - Seek to the previous/next chapter. If there are no chapters seek backward/forward 10 minutes.
- right mouse click - Seek to percentage in file corresponding to fraction of width.

Comment: yes @llogan sir I did check these shortcuts but I just wanted to know is a way to move video to a particular point as we do in any kind of video player using the slider is it possible in ffplay as I'm building a video editor I wanna show video before converting using FFmpeg so I'm using ffplay to show it so i though of adding a slider so user can check video as every video editor has it Thank you

Comment: @EswarT ffplay has no slider. See updated answer for an alternative.

Comment: thanks buddy will look into it Thanks a lot

Comment: sir i have posted another query please check it once "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67085953/merging-2-editing-videos-without-saving-them-using-ffmpeg" Thank you

Comment: How to step forward one frame?

Comment: ffplay really deserves some more dev love!